# Symfony 2, switching language does not work

Tags: php, symfony, translation

I wonder why when I click the links on the view to switch the language it doesn't work. If I set default locale to en or km, it will show English language or Khmer language respectively. What wrong with me, I can not click links below to switch the language? Please help me ! Many thanks in advanced for any answer.

In the view

```
<div class="col-sm-3 language-switcher">
    <a href="{{ path('ngs_locale', {locale: 'en'}) }}">English</a> |
    <a href="{{ path('ngs_locale', {locale: 'km'}) }}">ខ្មែរ</a>
</div>
```

routing.yml

```
ngs_locale:
path:     locale/{locale}
defaults: { _controller: NGSHomeBundle:Locale:locale }
```

LocaleController.php

```
namespace NGS\HomeBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class LocaleController extends Controller
{
    public function localeAction(Request $request, $locale)
    {
        /** ======== dump ========== **/
        dump($locale); //"km"
        $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);

        /** ======== dump ========== **/
        dump($request->getLocale()); //"en"

        $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');

        /** ======== dump ========== **/
        dump($referer);die; // null

        if (empty($referer)) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('ngs_not_found');
        }

        return $this->redirect($referer);
    }
}
```

LocaleListener.php

```
namespace NGS\HomeBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class LocaleListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $defaultLocale;

    public function __construct($defaultLocale = 'en')
    {
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
            return;
        }

        // try to see if the locale has been set as a _locale routing parameter
        if ($locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale')) {
            $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
        } else {
            // if no explicit locale has been set on this request, use one from the session
            $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
        }
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            // must be registered before the default Locale listener
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 17)),
        );
    }
}
```

Service.yml

```
services:
ngs_home.locale_listener:
    class: NGS\HomeBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener
    arguments: ["%kernel.default_locale%"]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Comment: Is this for the sticky locale? Do you not need to set your requirements on your routing file?

Comment: I'm not sure, I will try it.

Comment: I tried like below, but it does not working yet.

`ngs_locale:
    path:     locale/{locale}
    defaults: { _controller: NGSHomeBundle:Locale:locale }
    requirements:
        _locale:  en|km`

Comment: What is the error that your getting? Can you update your question with the error? or is there no error just that it will not change the _locale in the session?

Comment: No error show, but just not change the _locale in the session

Comment: Hang on a second, shouldn't your route be {_locale} not {locale}

Comment: when I put `locale/{_locale}`

Error: 
Controller "NGS\HomeBundle\Controller\LocaleController::localeAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$locale" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).

Comment: Have you enabled the default _locale in app/config/config.yml? and also left the requirements in? One downside I've noticed to this is that you have to put something in the url you can't just have /index you have to have /en/index

Comment: It look like this:
`default_locale:  "en"`

and in the url:

`http://ngs-sroul.dev/app_dev.php/locale/en`

Comment: Is your routing.yml in your app or in your /app/config/routing.yml

Comment: If this doesn't work I would try the Symfony IRC: http://symfony.com/irc they may be able to help a little more than I can.

Comment: My routing is location: 

NGS\HomeBundle\Resources\config\routing.yml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84101/discussion-between-liam-sorsby-and-fiemhong).

Comment: And thank for your support @Liam Sorsby

Comment: I will post some code in the chat for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I fixed my problem:
First, I changed the link: from locale to _locale

```
<div class="col-sm-3 language-switcher">
    <a href="{{ path('ngs_locale', {_locale: 'en'}) }}">English</a> |
    <a href="{{ path('ngs_locale', {_locale: 'km'}) }}">ខ្មែរ</a>
</div>
```

Second, I changed routing.yml, locale to _locale

```
ngs_locale:
    path:     locale/{_locale}
    defaults: { _controller: NGSHomeBundle:Locale:locale
```

Third, I changed LocaleController.php. Removed $locale parameter and then get $locale by $request->getLocale();

```
public function localeAction(Request $request)
{
    $locale = $locale = $request->getLocale();
    $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);

    $referer = $request->headers->get('referer');
    if (empty($referer)) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('ngs_not_found');
    }

    return $this->redirect($referer);
}
```

Fourth, I add DependencyInjection for HomeBundle DependencyInjection \Configuration.php and DependencyInjection \NGSHomeExtension.php

That's it !